# Converting Decimal to Roman Numeral in Java?

Tags: java, decimal, roman-numerals

I'm really new to computer science and I know that I'm most likely making very simple mistakes right now. I'm making a program to convert numbers to roman numerals and my 'Previous' variable just isn't working.

Edit for clarification:
Every numeral combination after V (X,L,C,D,M,) are over the mark. Also, my output treats input the same forward and backward. Ex:(IV=6)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class roman
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a Roman numeral: ");
        String R = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Converted to Decimal: " + RomanToDecimal(R));
    }

    static int RomanToDecimal(String R)
    {
        int Decimal = 0;
        char Previous;

        for (int x = 0; x < R.length(); x++)
        {
            Previous = R.charAt(x);
            if(R.charAt(x) == 'I')
                Decimal += 1;

            if(R.charAt(x) == 'V')
            {
                if (Previous == 'I')
                    Decimal -= 1;
                else
                    Decimal += 5;
            }

            if(R.charAt(x) == 'X')
            {
                if (Previous == 'I')
                    Decimal-= 1;
                else
                    Decimal+= 10;
            }

            if(R.charAt(x) == 'L')
            {
                if (Previous == 'X')
                    Decimal -= 10;
                else
                    Decimal+=50;
            }

            if(R.charAt(x) == 'C')
            {
                if (Previous == 'X')
                    Decimal -= 10;
                else
                    Decimal += 100;
            }

            if(R.charAt(x) == 'D')
            {
                if (Previous == 'C')
                    Decimal -= 100;
                else
                    Decimal += 500;
            }

            if(R.charAt(x) == 'M')
            {
                if (Previous == 'C')
                    Decimal -= 100;
                else
                    Decimal+= 1000;
            }

            Previous = R.charAt(x);
        }

        return Decimal;    
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote something like this into my `for` loop, but the program still output the same number back and forth.  I know that the`R.charAt()` is for position, but I'm unsure how to write the code in a way that the program registers one numeral preceding another.

Comment: `Previous = x > 0 ? R.charAt(x - 1) : '\0'`, or similar. You need to go "one character back", but also handle the case where you are at the first character in the string, and so can't go back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code corrected:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a Roman numeral: ");
        String R = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Converted to Decimal: " + RomanToDecimal(R));
    }

    static int RomanToDecimal(String R) {
        int Decimal = 0;
        char Previous = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < R.length(); x++) {
            if (R.charAt(x) == 'I')
                Decimal += 1;

            if (R.charAt(x) == 'V') {
                System.out.println(Previous);
                if (Previous == 'I') {
                    Decimal -= 2;
                }
                Decimal += 5;
            }

            if (R.charAt(x) == 'X') {
                if (Previous == 'I') {
                    Decimal -= 2;
                }
                Decimal += 10;
            }

            if (R.charAt(x) == 'L') {
                if (Previous == 'X') {
                    Decimal -= 20;
                }
                Decimal += 50;
            }

            if (R.charAt(x) == 'C') {
                if (Previous == 'X') {
                    Decimal -= 20;
                }
                Decimal += 100;
            }

            if (R.charAt(x) == 'D') {
                if (Previous == 'C') {
                    Decimal -= 200;
                }
                Decimal += 500;
            }

            if (R.charAt(x) == 'M') {
                if (Previous == 'C') {
                    Decimal -= 200;
                }
                Decimal += 1000;
            }
            Previous = R.charAt(x);
        }
        return Decimal;

    }
}
```

You weren't counting well on the behaviour when Previous character appears, not only you want to discount the previous added but you want to discount the same number from the next character so needs to be discounted twice.

Comment: Thank you this is actually working perfectly as far as I can see. Though, I did remove the System.out.println(Previous);.

Comment: Oops, sorry I left that from debugging.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple logic error.

If we run through your code step by step with an example input of `IX`, we can see that the first character read in is `I`, which causes the value of Decimal to be increased by 1. Then, when  we read in `X`, this we deduct 1 from Decimal, making it zero.

This means that the program outputs 0 for the input `IX`.

We should rethink how this program runs.

Comment: "10 is then added." Actually, it's not - read more closely.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry - teaches me for skim reading! Assumed, as the poster said result was always over! Edited.